# How do I submit a “file” input without submit button and then do a mysql update in the same script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

Hi This might be a little tricky but i feel i need a second eye to go over this ,so i have a form in a script. (This form is echo'd not predefined) I want to do an update in the database once a file is selected, I have managed to figure out how to do a form which submits once the file is selected the problem is how do I then proceed with the update without having to action the form away to another script. This line :

```
if (isset($_FILES['newcv']['name'])){
```

seems to be my problem as I keep getting an error with Undefined index newcv

**The Form**:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="newcv"/>
</form>
```

**The PHP code within the same script**:

```
$cvi = 9;
if (isset($_FILES['newcv']['name'])){
$file_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['newcv']['name']);
$tempname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['newcv']['tmp_name']);
$file_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['newcv']['type']);
$random = rand(23456789,98765432);
$target = "CVs/$random$file_name"; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['newcv']['tmp_name'],$target);
$update = "UPDATE users SET cv_name = '$file_name', cv = '$target' WHERE user_id = '$cvi'";
mysqli_query($con, $update);
}
```

Comment: And does it work flawlessy if you remove the automatic submission and submit the form manually ?

Comment: So basically your problem is the undefined index warning? What about `if (isset($_FILES['newcv'])) `?

Comment: @adeneo Yes it did when submitting manually.

Comment: @rlanvin nope that didnt work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Add enctype to your form tag and let me know if this do the trick

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: worked like a dream. I would send you a muffin if i was next door :)

Comment: I assume i got your Muffin @GeraldGray ;-) Please Select The Answer for others help.